# How to signout user in asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to sign out a user when a session object don't exist with following code in my View:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

But this doesn't work - the user is already authenticated.

I've seen that the default LogOff `Controller` Action use this code to signout a user:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
```

But I can't use this code in my view.

So how can I logout a user in my View? Or when it's not possible how can I do this in a Controller?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: The default LogOff action (or a copy) simply needs to be called.  This can be a javasript call or an actual `a` link.

Comment: When I call this in my Controller "RedirectToAction("LogOff", "Account");" so my user is allready authenticatet.

Comment: You keep saying...the user is already authenticated.  What does that mean?  Of course they are, you are wanting to "unauthenticate" them.  Also, the sign out will not be "noticed" by your code until a new request is made by the user.  Meaning, if you call `AuthenticationManager.SignOut();` and on the next line have `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;` - it will still show true.

Comment: @Tommy Okay .. thats a good hint. So how can I set IsAuthenticated to false? User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false; - don't work .. it's readonly

Comment: You have to redirect the user or somehow issue a new request to the server.  Call SignOut();, redirect somewhere else.  That issues a new request (which the client will send the updated cookies the just received from the previous request, the one you signed them out in) and the updated authentication status will then be available.

Answer (score 3):

You would be doing this in a controller, for instance in a separate action like `LogOut()`. After you've done your logout, redirect the user to the front page (for instance).

Then you simply make a link to that action.

The view is not a place to contain anything but purely simple presentational logic, like `if` statements or `for` loops. Controllers should take care of application behaviour like logging out.

Comment: I have supposed something like this, but how I do this when this function "FormsAuthentication.SignOut()" is not working and with this function "AuthenticationManager.SignOut()" I get an error that AuthenticationManager does't include an implementation for this function?